# Sublayer of a layer's UIView showing fine in Storyboard as @IBDesignable, but not in the simulator

Tags: uiview, calayer, ios8

I have UIView with a sublayer attached to the layer of UIView. UIView has the @IBDesignable-tag and is perfectly shown in the storyboard.

However if I launch the application in the simulator the sublayer does not show up. I don't get any error messages, the sublayer just doesn't show.

Does anyone have an idea how I could debug this problem or any other idea about the cause ? I tried to debug it with the new "Debug View Hierarchy"-Button in the debugger's toolbar, but unfortunately it shows only the views and not the layers !

Here is my configuration:

- Xcode 6 Golden Master
- the UIView-code is in Swift
- iOS 8

Here in dropbox you can find the Xcode-project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uejq7j74qyx715x/ArcProblem.zip?dl=0

The view causing the problem is called "RotateMeterView.swift"

Comment: I'm running into the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

The Problem is finally solved: I opened a TSI with apple. it came out, that it was a Programming error from my part. Please find here the answer provided by Apple:

You should not be using the frame of view to calculate the position of subviews.  In fact you should never access a view's frame from within the view itself.  Instead, use the bounds property which returns values in the current view's coordinate space.  See the [View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html) for more information.

So this line:

```
circleLayer.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(frame), y:frame.origin.y + frame.height - radius - dy)
```

should become:

```
circleLayer.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(bounds), y:bounds.origin.y + bounds.height - radius - dy)
```

Also, you should not be positioning and sizing subviews in a function that will only be called once at view load.  View sizes can and do change after they are loaded (e.g. during rotation).  Your view should be overriding `-layoutSubviews` and positioning the circleLayer there.

Comment: What you said about overriding `-layoutSubviews` and positioning the CALayer there saved me after hours of searching.  Many thanks!

Comment: Same here. Wish you eternal life